# If FindNextUrlCacheEntry() fails, how can I retrieve info of the failed entry again?

Tags: caching, wininet

I got a `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` error when invoking `FindNextUrlCacheEntry()`. Then I want to retrieve the failed entry again, using a enlarged buffer. But I found that when I invoke `FindNextUrlCacheEntry()`, it seems I was retrieving the one next to the failed entry. Is there any approach I can go back to retrieve the information of the just failed entry?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem, is there a maximal size I can allocate in order to avoid `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`?

Answer (score 2):

I also observed the same behavior on XP.  I am trying to clear IE cache programmatically using WinInet APIs. The code at the following MSDN link works perfectly fine on Win7/Vista but deletes cache files in batches(multiple runs) on XP. On debugging I found that API FindNextUrlCacheEntry gives different sizes for the same entry when executed multiple times.

MSDN Link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815718

Here is what I am doing:

First of all I make a call to determine the size of the next URL entry

fSuccess = FindNextUrlCacheEntry(hCacheHandle, 0, &cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial) // cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial = 0 at this point

The above call returns false with error no as INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER and with cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial  parameter set equal to the size of the buffer required to retrieve the cache entry, in bytes. After allocating the required size (cacheEntryInfoBufferSizeInitial) I call the same WinInet API again expecting it to retrieve the entry successfully this time. But sometimes it fails. I see that the cases in which API fails again even though with required buffered sizes (as determined it only) because it expects morebytes then what it retrieved earlier. Most of times the difference is of few bytes but I have also seen cases where the difference is almost 4 to 5 times.

Comment: I have experienced this as well. I simply allocate (yet again) the NEW size returned and that seems to work for a subsequent call to `FindNextUrlCacheEntry()` Have you figured out why different sizes are returned?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth this seems to be solved in Vista.